# Changing privilege level of VM at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, privilege

We require admin privileges when running our Java code on a Windows 7/8 platform. The privilege level is breaking the Drag-and-Drop capability. As I understand it, Windows disallows drag-and-drop from, say, Windows Explorer running at a lower privilege level from sending a message to an application (our Java VM in this instance) with higher privileges  due to the Windows inter-process security architecture.

We require the admin level only at Java VM startup and are willing to reduce the privilege level upon completion of certain restricted tasks so as to allow drag-and-drop to function. Is there a way for the Java code to request such as adjustment at runtime without relaunching itself with the assistance of other wrappers or scripts?